# Why do I have to wrap the functions of my onClick attributes in anonymous functions in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-function, jsx

Sorry for the confusing title; if I have an onClick attribute on one of my components such as the following

```
<Component onClick={this.doSomething()} />
```

I will often get weird errors depending on what the doSomething() function is actually calling. If doSomething() is changing state particularly I get all sorts of render errors. On the other hand if I do this

```
var _this = this;
<Component onClick{
   function(){
      _this.doSomething()
   }
} />
```

All the errors go away and everything works as I intended. What exactly am I doing by wrapping my onClick attribute in an anonymous function that makes this work? Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: You can do `onClick={ _this.doSomething }`

Comment: @Rajesh Not always. There's a good chance you'll need `this.doSomething.bind(this)` too.

Comment: @BenFortune Yes you are right. We might have to do that.

Comment: I found this weird too that you have to define "_this" to be "this". Probably because in function(){}, it is another context where "this" points to the new context. However, as you define "_this" to be "this" outside the function(), then you can preserve the context outside function() by using "_this".

Comment: @BenFortune a question, if I'm doing `_this.doSomething`, will react not associate `this` to `_this`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do this:

```
<Component onClick={this.doSomething()} />
```

Then you're *calling* the function and assigning the return value to the `onClick` attribute. If `this.doSomething()` modifies the component state during a render, then this will cause problems.

You should be able to use:

```
<Component onClick={this.doSomething} />
```

i.e. remove the `()`, so the function is assigned to the attribute, rather than the result of executing the function.

In the constructor of your component class, you should include the following line:

```
this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
```

You can use `onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)}` too but this means that a new function is created every time the component is re-rendered.

The binding behaviour of `this` within a component class varies, depending on how the component is created:

- Using the `class` keyword (ES6), `this` is not automatically bound
- Using `React.createClass`, `this` is bound

With ES7, you also have a couple more options:

- Using `doSomething = () => { //...` instead of the `function` keyword
- Using `onClick={::this.doSomething}`, a shorthand way to bind `this`

Thanks to [Zequez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887194/zequez) for their useful comment.

Comment: If you are using react `createClass` it is. If you are using ES6 classes it's not. However, if you are using ES7 you can define a class method as a property with `classMethod = () => {}` instead of `function classMethod () {}` and it will be automatically bound, or you can do `::this.doSomething` which is a shorthand of `.bind(this)`.

Comment: I didn't know about the double colon syntax.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Zequez, I updated my answer to include the details from your comment.

Comment: What if I wanted to pass parameters into the function on click though? What if I wanted to say onClick={this.doSomething(value)}. I have to include the parenthesis to pass in a value don't I?

Comment: @EllDoubleYew yes, in this case you need to use an anonymous function (as you have done in your question), taking care to keep `this` in scope.